# Silverlight duration tooltip

Tags: silverlight, tooltip, codeplex

I'm trying to increase the length of time that a tooltip displays in a silverlight application. I downloaded Silverlight.Controls.ToolTip from codeplex and I add it as a reference. Here is my code in my xaml:

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Silverlight.Controls.ToolTips;assembly=Silverlight.Controls.ToolTips"

<Button Content="button content">
    <Controls:ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <Controls:ToolTip DisplayTime="00:00:10" InitialDelay="00:00:03">
            <TextBlock Text="tooltip"></TextBlock>
        </Controls:ToolTip>
    </Controls:ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

The code compiles. However, while running the code I get an error "XamlParseException occurred The attachable property 'ToolTip' was not found in 'ToolTipService.' Any ideas on what is causing this error? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the reference isn't correct, perhaps a DLL is not available at runtime.  The XAML looks right.

Comment: @ Chis Nicol When I look at the properties of the reference the path is D:\Project\Src\MySolution\Bin\Debug\Silverlight.Controls.ToolTips.dll. Do you recognize any problems with that being the location?

Comment: @ChrisNicol I've also tried having the path be C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\Silverlight.Controls.ToolTips.dll, which hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded this DLL from web and have not unblocked it yet.

Right Click on the DLL, go to properties and unblock it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is how I solved it.

1) Go to: http://tooltipservice.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest

2) Download the Source Code

3) Copy "ToolTip.cs", "ToolTipService.cs" and ToolTipTimer.cs from
   "branches\2.2.0\Silverlight.Controls.ToolTips\" into your own project somewhere.

4) Now point the xmlns to assembly on your own project where you have copied the source file into.

So basically, just use the source file instead of the dll and it will work. This has worked for me, hope it works for you.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing the ToolTip DLL from another DLL, try also adding a reference to it into you main project.